# Mongoose: TypeError: Method Uint8Array.length called on incompatible receiver

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm making a small website with i18n. When starting I used local json files, but after switching to mongodb I experience an error I don't understand. A good explanation is highly appreciated.

The error I get is this:

> TypeError: Method Uint8Array.length called on incompatible receiver [object Object]

I structure i18n data with "da" and "en" properties. I then use a method for filtering relevant language.

Here are examples of my data, both json and corresponding mongoose result. Both copied from terminal (printed with `console.log`):

**json**

```
[ { lang: { da: 'Dansk', en: 'Danish' }, rating: 5 },
  { lang: { da: 'Engelsk', en: 'English' }, rating: 5 },
  { lang: { da: 'Tysk', en: 'German' }, rating: 5 } ]
```

**mongoose**

```
[ { _id: 57e2561369e4bc0a8ca6c630,
    lang: { da: 'Dansk', en: 'Danish' },
    rating: 5,
    id: '57e2561369e4bc0a8ca6c630' },
  { _id: 57e2561369e4bc0a8ca6c631,
    lang: { da: 'Engelsk', en: 'English' },
    rating: 5,
    id: '57e2561369e4bc0a8ca6c631' },
  { _id: 57e2561369e4bc0a8ca6c632,
    lang: { da: 'Tysk', en: 'German' },
    rating: 5,
    id: '57e2561369e4bc0a8ca6c632' } ]
```

**filterLanguage method**

```
var traverse = require('traverse');
var filterLanguage = function(language, obj) {
    return traverse(obj).map(function (item) {
        if (this.key === language) {
            this.parent.update(item);
        }
    });
};
```

So `filterLanguage('da', languages);` should return something like:

```
[ { lang: 'Dansk', rating: 5 },
  { lang: 'Engelsk', rating: 5 },
  { lang: 'Tysk', rating: 5 } ]
```

`filterLanguage()` works on a local, valid JSON file but not on the Mongoose result set...

I tried `JSON.stringify(obj)`. I also tried setting `toObject()` method in Mongoose models but no luck.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

**--------- EDIT ---------**

**Model**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var languageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    local: {
        lang: { da: String, en: String },
        rating: Number
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Language', languageSchema);
```

**Query**

```
language.find({}, function(err, results) {
    var obj = filterLanguage(lang, results.languages);
    console.log(obj);
});
```

I tried setting `toObject` on the schema like this:

```
languageSchema.set('toObject', { virtuals: true });
```

Comment: What is `traverse()`? Why are you passing `results.experience` while that doesn't seem to be part of your schema?

Comment: Updated question: traverse is a npm library for traversing js objects. experience was a copy/paste error, should have been languages.

Beware this is a simplified example, not the complete code. So it's easier to get an overview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is related to `traverse` not being able to handle `ObjectId` instances in your `results` array.

Since it looks like you don't use `_id` or `id`, the easiest way to fix this is to exclude those properties from the result documents:

```
language.find({}, '-_id -id', function(err, results) { ... })
```

(`-id` is probably superfluous, because it's a virtual that depends on `_id`)

Comment: Thank you! Do you know why traverse cant handle ObjectId? It only recognized native JS types or...?

Comment: @olefrank it's actually a bit more complicated than I initially thought. When you _just_ run `filterLanguage()` it works just fine. However, once you want to use the result of that function for something (like `console.log`), the error occurs. Perhaps `traverse` "breaks" `ObjectId` instances (or more specifically, using `traverse(...).map()` breaks it).